# October CMS - Extend the Media Manager

Tags: laravel-5, extend, octobercms

I am trying to extend the functionality of the October CMS media manager. 
The class I would like to extend is `Cms\Widgets\MediaManager` so I can override its `checkUploadPostback()` function.

Is this possible in October? I only found documentation for extending other plugins, not a core class.

Comment: Did you achieve this? I was wondering what is the best approach

Comment: Unfortunately not. We ultimately abandoned October CMS as it did not seem to be well maintained by the creators. We now use Prismic or Contentful for our CMS and then build micro services for needs beyond those provided by those CMSs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a useful article to extend part of the functionality...
[BIND MEDIA MANAGER TO CUSTOM FORM WIDGET](https://octobercms.com/forum/post/bind-media-manager-to-custom-form-widget)

Comment: This does not extend the media manager. The example you provided integrates Media Manager into another Plugin which is different. He is asking how to override its functionalities in the backend.